# Firebase/Firecloud & React - How to store profile images to not need 80 different reads to display all the 80 images?

Tags: reactjs, image, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, icons

I'm setting up a React and Firecloud app that displays profiles based on a set of constraints. Based on the users choices, +- 10-100 profile snapshots will be displayed, including the profile image/icon.

All advice online seems to point to using the Firebase storage with the image links within my Collections' Documents. 
Now in my mind that means every time a user changes the constraints or refreshes (the info changes pretty often so reluctant to rely on local storage) I will need one read to download all of my profile snapshots (stored in one document) and another 1-100 reads to download each image, is this the only way to do this?

The images/icons are small low resolution pics.
Ideally I'd love to store these with each profile within the document, but cannot figure out how as the only data options are string, number, boolean, map, array, null, timestamp, geopoint or reference.

Or have I got this completely wrong and downloading all of the images counts as only one read? (cost is the main concern with firecloud charging per read and write)

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [this](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) if you haven't already. There is a lot of information that could be useful.

"You can also retrieve multiple documents with one request by querying documents in a collection. For example, you can use `where()` to query for all of the documents that meet a certain condition, then use `get()` to retrieve the results :

```
db.collection("cities").where("capital", "==", true)
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```

By default, Cloud Firestore retrieves all documents that satisfy the query in ascending order by document ID, but you can order and limit the data returned."

[Paginating data with query cursors](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/query-cursors) also might be of your interest.